# Embedded HSQLDB persist data to a file

Tags: hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I am creating a spring based web application that uses embedded hsqldb. 
My spring config is pretty simple:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" >
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:scripts/create-table-if-not-exists" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

But with this config all data is stored in memory. Here is the data source url that is created

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource
```

I need to persist data to a file. So that I can use it again after server restart.

Comment: If you need to persist it, then why do you use the `mem` mode?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did not specify mem mode. I assume this is default configuration created by spring.

Comment: `jdbc:embedded-database` in Spring means a mem: database. Define a database youself with file: in the URL.

Comment: roytuts.com/embedded-hsql-database-with-spring/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution worked for me

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:#{systemProperties['user.home']}/db/data" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:scripts/create-table-if-not-exists" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Comment: In other words, the solution to persisting data from an embedded HSQLDB database is not to use an embedded database.

Comment: @Paul - I am working with a Spring MVC web application that simulates an in-memory persistence layer that is Map based. Obviously, a database is much more performant, so I want to use HSQLDB. I want the database to be embedded, i.e. start and stop with the application, but I want the data to be permanent, i.e. file-based. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @WebUser, my earlier comment was in error.  I should have said that "the solution to persisting data from an in-memory database is not to use an in-memory database."  The solution presented in the accepted answer should work for you - the data is stored in a file and the database itself is embedded.

Comment: @Paul that certainly helps. Thanks!